# How long does Star Anise keep?

Tags: storage-lifetime

The jar or packet at either of my local stores is quite big.   How long does it stay effective, once opened?   Given Star Anise is quite hard, I'm thinking it may last a while.  But would I be better vacuum sealing half or 2/3?

[edited to correct grammar.  rmjf]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to vacuum seal it. You can store it dry in a sealed bag or container. It will last years. The flavour might deteriorate over time though.

Comment: I think the flavour deteriorating over time is presumably exactly what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Fair, for a point of reference: I have a large bag of whole star anise and they are still fragrant after a year of storage

Comment: Freezing the spices is a nice way the flavour fresh for longer periods of time

Comment: Yes it is the fragrance I'm concerned about.  I was assuming they cant go 'off'.

Answer (score 4):

They should last a long while if properly stored in an airtight container in a dry place.

Answer (score 1):

I had star anise in a closed jar for five years after a move;  I just used it and although a little dry and a little less potent, the flavor is still there. However, I don't know how long the nutritional effects last, such as the purported gut health. I'll get some fresh soon.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a bag of star anise that I bought ca. 2013 and kept in the freezer.  I haven't noticed a huge difference between the old stuff and the new that I bought straight from the (I'm assuming high turnover) bulk jar of my coop.